# Solid line under navbar with ::after

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to build my navbar and I seem kind of stuck. I've been trying to get a solid yellow line about 3-5px thick underneath my navbar.

I remember I have made a navbar in the past that looked like what I am trying to do but I forgot how to do that and I have lost that document.

So I have used: nav::after and tried border-bottom but it does not do anything..

```css
nav {
    background:black;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}
nav::after {
    border-bottom: 8px solid green;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul .nav-links {
    float:right;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:40px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
    margin-right:30px;

}
nav a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    transition:.2s ease-in-out;
    font-weight:700;
}
nav a:hover {
    color:#FFE600;
}
.nav-title {
    line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-title"><h2>text text</h2><h4>is a text, text text text</h4></li>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Statistics">Statistics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#what">What can you do?</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: just add position: relative to the nav :) also you need to select it like #nav

Comment: thank you @PatrikAlexits :) worked

Comment: Sorry but why not just apply the border directly to the nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need '::after'--you can remove that. The border-bottom of the div will automatically be shown at the bottom of the div.

Answer (score 1):

```
#nav{
    position: relative;
}
```

You need to use the "#" css selector, to specify, you are referring to the element with the `id` => nav. (it look cleaner)

Position relative means, the child element will be absolutely positioned RELATIVE to the parent. (which has this attribute setted)